# jquery cycle cssBefore, animIn, animOut dont accept relative values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made a custom slide-transition with jquery cycle plugin which make the use of options: cssBefore, animIn, animOut necessary.

There are two slideshows with different widths side by side on desktopview with a fixed width.
There is a media query breakpoint, where the shows get one below the other and are supposed to get a width of 100%, which works fine so far, except one thing:

Because the cycle option accepting number values (for px) only, the transition don't adapts to the width of 100%.

**Question is:**

How can I make it so, that relative values are accepted?

And if this is not possible, is there another slider which offers the same transition as shown in the following example?

My Code:

HTML:

```
<div id="all">
  <div id="s1" class="pics">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach1.jpg" />
    <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach2.jpg" />
  </div>    
  <div id="s2" class="pics">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach3.jpg" />
    <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach1.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $('#s1').cycle({
    timeout: 0,
    speed: 500,
    fx: 'custom', 
    sync: 0, 
    cssBefore: {  
        top:  0, 
        left: -300, // <-- relative values here would be perfect
        display: 'block' 
    }, 
    animIn:  { 
        left: 0 
    }, 
    animOut: {  
        left: -300  // <-- relative values here would be perfect
    }, 
    cssAfter: {  
        zIndex: 0  
    },
    delay: -1000 
  });
  $('#s2').cycle({
    timeout: 0,
    speed: 500,
    fx: 'custom', 
    sync: 0, 
    cssBefore: {  
        top:  0, 
        left: 700,  // <-- relative values here would be perfect
        display: 'block' 
    }, 
    animIn:  { 
        left: 0 
    }, 
    animOut: {  
        left: 700  // <-- relative values here would be perfect
    }, 
    cssAfter: {  
        zIndex: 0  
    },
    delay: -1000 
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
#all {width: 1000px;}
#s1 {width: 30%;}
#s2 {width: 70%;}
.pics {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
height: 250px;
}
img {
display: block;
height: 250px;
width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) { 
  #s1, #s2 {
    float: none;
    width:100%;    
  }
}
```

[See the example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yogreyym/16/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is any plugin BUT you can use Media Queries for example:

```
 @media (max-width: 600px) { 
  #s2 {
    width:300px;
    font-size:14px;    
   }
  }
```

this css will be executed when the screen size is less than or equal to `600px` ONLY. and if the screen size is more than `600px` your main css will be executed.

For full documentation about media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

media query demo: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/media-queries/

I hope this helps.